# How can I decompress a GZip compressed file in chunks in memory?

Tags: gzip, compression

I can decompress a small GZip file in memory but there are memory limitations on the cloud box that this will run on. I can get around this by doing it in chunks (~32 k).  Is there an easy way to split up a GZip compressed file without reading through it?
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to read a gzip file in chunks. No, you cannot split a gzip file without decoding it.